# Exceljs writing file

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, hapi.js, exceljs

I am getting data from DB and trying to populate the excel file. Unable to populate the excel file.
The code for writing data is as follow.

```
await users();
    console.log("data " + JSON.stringify(test));
    workbook1.xlsx.writeFile("testing.xlsx").then(function () {
        worksheet.addRow(test);
        console.log(test);
    });
```

user function is follow

```
function users() {
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    constants.sequelize.query(`SELECT collectionName FROM DB.[collection] WHERE id = '1234567'`).then(user => {
        console.log(user);
        test = user;
        resolve(user);
        console.log("out");
    }).catch(error => {
        reject(error);
    });
});
```

}

And the data in "test" is as follow

```
[[{"collectionName":"some name"}],[{"collectionName":"another name"}]]
```

EDIT:
it should be 
worksheet.addRows(test);
And should be outside the "writeFile"

Comment: Where is your "test" variable is defined?

Comment: outside the module.exports. I am getting the data in "test" variable. it is in this format [{"collectionName":"some name"}]

Comment: Which npm module are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `addRows` not `addRow` :

```
worksheet.addRows(test); // < --------- as 'test' is array of multiple rows
```

instead of

```
worksheet.addRow(test);
```

Comment: it works but also it should be outside the writeFile.